# Java type variable dependency mismatch

Tags: java, variables, generics, types, compilation

Can you please explain to me why am I getting this error when trying to define?

**a generic class:**

```java
public class GenericClass<T, S extends T> {
    ...
}
```

**`Main.java`:**

```java
public class Main(){
     public static void main(String[] args){

         // This line generates compilation error
         GenericClass<Number, Integer> object = new GenericClass();
     }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Bound mismatch: The type Integer is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <S extends T> of the type GenericClass<T,S>
```

**[SOLVED]**

I had another class in my project called Integer :)

**Thank you very much for quick response**

Comment: What error? Please [edit] the question and include it.

Comment: Are you considering, *Unchecked assignment of GenericClass to GenericClass<java.lang.Number, java.lang.Integer>*  as a compiler error?

Comment: You are using a raw type on the right side of the `=`. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Comment: Just updated the question.

Comment: Don't ever use the same name as a common standard API type for a custom type. You should consider names from `java.lang` and `java.util` off limits.

Answer (score 3):

This code compiles and runs fine.

There's no compilation error, however as explained by nullpointer, there's a warning:

```
Unchecked assignment of GenericClass to GenericClass<java.lang.Number, java.lang.Integer>
```

An easy way to fix this is to replace your code line with this:

```
// Java 6 and lower
GenericClass<Number, Integer> object = new GenericClass<Number, Integer>();

// Java 7 and higher, using the diamond operator
GenericClass<Number, Integer> object = new GenericClass<>();
```